# Adding quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following in javascript..

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";
```

How can I achieve the result that equals "600mins"?

Comment: `'"' + one + two + '"'`

Comment: or `"\"" + one + two + "\""`

Comment: You should clarify if you want the string `"600mins"` as a result or the string `600mins`. It's hard to tell from your current description, although the title would indicate you might want the quotes in the result.

Comment: Do you really want to have quotation marks in the **value**? Do you mean the result should be equal to the value created by the *string literal* `"600mins"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";
var result = one + two;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concat both vars:

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";

var result = one + two;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";

console.log(one + two); // "600mins"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var result = one + two;
```

?

The result will equal "600mins"

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Simply add them together. JavaScript will automatically cast the number to a string, add it to "mins", and the result is a string.

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";    
var three = one + two; // value of three is now "600mins"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate them to obtain "600mins" (without the quotes)

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";

var three = one + two
```

If you want to wrap it in quotes, you can do this :

```
three = "\"" + three + "\"";
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3zaj8w5z/

Answer (score 0):

```
var one = 600;
var two = "mins";
var result= one.concat(two);
if(result == "600mins")
     alert("It works");
```

Is that what you wanted?